# How to insert directly into a stash?

Tags: perl, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a pragma for defining a bunch of constants, like this:

```
use many::constant
    one_constant => 1,
    other_constant => 2,
;
```

The relevant portion of my import looks like

```
package many::constant;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub import {
    my ($class, @constants) = @_;

    my $caller_nms = do {
        no strict 'refs';
        \%{caller.'::'}
    };

    while (my ($name, $value) = splice @constants, 0, 2) {
        *{$caller_nms->{$name}} = sub () { $value };
    }
}
```

I expect the `$caller_nms` stash to auto-vivify when assigned to like this, but I'm getting an error "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference".  Is there a way to get this assignment to work like I expect?  I ended up changing the assignment to:

```
my $caller_glob = do {
    no strict 'refs';
    \*{caller.'::'.$name}
};
*$caller_glob = sub () { $value };
```

but that feels less elegant to me.

Comment: Don't be afraid of `no strict 'refs'`! While `strict` is a good help for >99% of programs, there are enough cases where it has to be turned off. Yes, you can hide it inside small scopes or behind [modules like `Package::Stash`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Package::Stash), but it will always be there. I just turn it off inside the loop where I need a symref (in your case: inside the `while`). That's the smallest possible scope that doesn't require extra hassle.

Comment: agreed with amon, although I would say that Package::Stash is pretty great and hides some of the more annoying features of working with stashes directly.

Comment: amon, can you convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`use constant`](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) as a baseline and actually examine the source: [`constant.pm`](https://metacpan.org/source/SAPER/constant-1.27/lib/constant.pm).

That's essentially what it does as well:

```
my $pkg = caller;
# ...
{
    no strict 'refs';
    my $full_name = "${pkg}::$name";
    # ...
    my @list = @_;
    *$full_name = sub () { @list };
}
```

Also, note that the `constant` module has this feature: [`constant #Defining multiple constants at once`](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#Defining-multiple-constants-at-once)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant {
    one_constant => 1,
    other_constant => 2,
};

print one_constant, ' - ', other_constant, "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
1 - 2
```